# linux wlan0 network disabled(error siocsifflags operation not permitted), how to enable it?

Tags: linux

I am new to linux, working on backtrack, I just configured my usb network adapter  tp link 725 n comes as wlan2.
The command(lshw) is showing network disabled for wlan2, I have tried several rfkill commands but they are not showing any output.

The command "ifconfig wlan2 up" giving output as "siocsifflags operation not permitted".

```
root@bt:~# lshw -c
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.14
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
   lshw -version

-version        print program version (B.02.14)

format can be
-html           output hardware tree as HTML
-xml            output hardware tree as XML
-short          output hardware paths
-businfo        output bus information

options can be
-class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
-C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
-c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
-disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
-enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
-quiet          don't display status
-sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial          numbers, etc.)
-numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
```

Comment: 1. this is NOT programming question; 2. show us output of `lshw -C`

Comment: @KING Rather than add comments, please edit your original question with this information and code samples. This will make it much easier for others who read this page to see and understand what you're asking. Thank you!

Comment: thanx @MikeZavarello i m new here , tryin my best!

Comment: any help from u @OleksandrKravchuk

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you weren't root when executing the ifconfig command...

Comment: i even used sudo ifconfig wlan up